# How to create a file stream and write to the stream asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, typescript, file, promise

I am new to TypeScript/JavaScript and Node.
Now I am trying to create a file stream and write "Hello!" to the stream asynchronously.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import fs from 'fs';

function createStream(filePath: string): Promise<fs.WriteStream> {

  return new Promise<fs.WriteStream>((resolve, reject) => {

    const out = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    out.on('close', () => {
      console.log(filePath + ' closed');
      resolve(out);
    });

    out.on('error', (err: any) => {
      console.log(filePath + ' ' + err);
      reject(err);
    });

  });
}

createStream('/tmp/test.txt').then((out:fs.WriteStream) => {
  console.log(out);
  out.write('Hello!');
  out.end();
})
```

This code does create `/tmp/test.txt` but prints out nothing and the file is empty.
What is the problem with this code ?

Comment: The promise returned by `createStream` appears to be resolved when the stream *closes*, so in the `then` callback you're trying to write *after* that. I am reading that right?

Comment: Yes, the `createStream` promise is resolved when the stream closes. The promise is pending since nobody closes the stream. That's why the `then` function is never called.

Comment: Thank you ! I am getting it. Just wondering why the script exits while the stream promise is pending.

Comment: Node shouldn't exit while there are tasks in the queue, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will rewrite the script again.

Comment: You have a "hole in my bucket, dear Liza, dear Liza" situation.
(1) The `.then(...)` handler won't be called until the Promise is fulfilled.
(2) The Promise is fulfilled is only when the file stream is closed.
(3) The file stream is closed only by a statement in the `.then(...)` handler.

Comment: @jonrsharpe writable streams don't create a reference that keeps the event loop running, and neither do promises. That's why the program exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to resolve a promise with the `fs.WriteStream` since its creation is synchronous. Just call `fs.createWriteStream()` directly and pass the instance to your function to create a promise that settles when the stream closes or errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import fs from 'fs';
import stream from 'stream';

function promisify(s: stream.Stream): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const onClose = () => {
      s.off('error', onError);
      resolve();
    };
    const onError = (error: Error) => {
      s.off('close', onClose);
      reject(error);
    };

    s.once('close', onClose);
    s.once('error', onError);
  });
}

const out = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');

promisify(out).then(() => {
  console.log('Done');
});

out.write('Hello!');
out.end();
```